# Why won't cmake permit <> style include?

Tags: c++, cmake, directory, cmakelists-options

I am very new to cmake, but I am using it on Visual Studio to develop a program that has to run on linux. I need to include the following in this manner:

```
#include <xscontroller/xscontrol_def.h>
#include <xscontroller/xsdevice_def.h>
#include <xscontroller/xsscanner.h>
#include <xstypes/xsoutputconfigurationarray.h>
#include <xstypes/xsdatapacket.h>
#include <xstypes/xstime.h>
#include <xscommon/xsens_mutex.h>
```

However, the files are only recognize by visual studio when I do the following:

```
#include "xscontroller/xscontrol_def.h"
#include "xscontroller/xsdevice_def.h"
#include "xscontroller/xsscanner.h"
#include "xstypes/xsoutputconfigurationarray.h"
#include "xstypes/xsdatapacket.h"
#include "xstypes/xstime.h"
#include "xscommon/xsens_mutex.h"
```

The structure of my project in VS is fairly simple:

```
ANT
-out
-xscommon
-xscontroller
-xstypes
-ANT.cpp
-CMakeLists.txt
.
.
.
```

The includes I need are in the three xs folder, and I believe they have to be referenced with <> both in visual studio and when the code is compiled onto linux, as the references within each header are done in <> form, which is what causes this error:

```
xscallbackplainc.h:68:10: fatal error: xstypes/pstdint.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xstypes/pstdint.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

at compilation.

Concisely, I really just need to know what command (whether it be in CMakeLists.txt or somewhere else) will allow this kind of referencing within the project and the compiled project over ssh on linux. I am aware of the difference between `#include ""` and `#include <>`, I am however new to cmake, and have looked everywhere and cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this is using `include_directories` command. Simply add the following to your `ANT/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Though I would highly recommend using `target_include_directories()` instead. The difference between the two is that `target_include_directories()` specifies include directories just for one **target**[1].

[1]. A **target** is anything specified via `add_executable()` or `add_library()`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(ANT)

add_executable(ANT ANT.cpp) #other source files as necessary

#format of target_include_directories:
# target_include_directories(target_name PUBLIC|PRIVATE PATH_TO_DIR) 

target_include_directories(ANT PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

Comment: Okay that has solved the including issue, thank you so much. Is linking a similar situation? What am I looking for when including libs for Linux programs? I don't see any .lib files, but I see a fair few .cpp.o, c.o, and .a files...my reading has told me those are significant, and I think they are the cause of a few unresolved references, as I don't know how to include them.

Comment: linking is done using `target_link_libraries(target_name PUBLIC|PRIVATE LIBRARY_NAME}` where library name can be a shared library or a static library built inside your project. You can do `add_library(lib lib.c source_files...)` before `add_executable()` and then link like `target_link_libraries(ANT PRIVATE lib)`

Comment: For external libraries you have to usually find them first using `find_library()` or `find_package()` and then link using `target_link_libraries()`.  If you are still stuck, I would suggest posting another question *with* your cmake file and what libraries you want to link / build.

Comment: I'll go ahead and do that now. My includes are working, just not the links to libraries. (I'm hoping those mean the same thing in cmake as they do in visual studio)

Comment: include and linking is different cmake.

Comment: I have posted the question, hopefully it makes sense. Should be clear I don't know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

I have posted the question about linking, hopefully it makes sense. Should be clear I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: You posted this post as an **answer**, but that content is not an answer. I see you have similar comment posted for your question post, so just delete that "answer".